# Feature query for using rmarkdown and r-exams as maths question database

Tags: r-markdown, r-exams

I'm planning to become a maths teacher next year. Since work is pretty quiet for me at the moment, I want to build a database of maths questions so that I have resources to work with next year. Rmarkdown and R-Exams look promising, but there are a few things I'm not yet clear about.

The list below shows my requirements. Those items in italics are requirements that I want input on.

#### What I must be able to do

- Database of questions that I can mix-and-match into quizzes.
- Export to both PDF and HTML.

  - *Not just multiple choice. Must have at minimum the ability to just display the question*
    or to display the question followed by space left afterwards.
- To be able to display or hide solutions.
- Question randomisation

#### What I would like to be able to do

- Export quizzes to a variety of Learning Management Systems.
- *Grade questions with a Computer Algebra System.*

  - I listed this one because I've seen people use moodle STACK with excellent results. However, it doesn't meet my portability requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The randomization and mix-and-match strategy is at the very core of R/exams so clearly this is supported. The export to different output formats (PDF, HTML, Docx, different learning management systems) is also fundamental feature of R/exams, see: http://www.R-exams.org/intro/oneforall/.

How to do the fine control of the layout in PDF exports (title page, hiding solutions, spacing between questions, etc.) is summarized in the `vignette("exams", package = "exams")` [[PDF]](https://CRAN.R-project.org/web/packages/exams/vignettes/exams.pdf). There are also various questions related to the `exams2pdf()` interface here on StackOverflow.

As for grading I'm not sure what this should look like. It seems to me to be orthogonal to what R/exams does. But maybe I'm missing the point here. If you correct quizzes in PDF format you will typically assign points "by hand" - and if you are using a learning management system, that will assign the points. And then based on the points you can assign grades in any tool you like.

Comment: Thanks for your response and apologies about my earlier partial reply.

I have since figured out that I can code open ended questions by choosing extype: string and having some string (possibly arbitrary) as the solution. These type of questions would only be used for written assignments.

As for the CAS-assisted grading: it's a feature that some programmes used in tertiary education have. For example, my wife is a lecturer and at her university, they use moodle STACK to grade responses, which gives them a lot more flexibility.

Comment: Since I want a solution that is equally happy across a variety of learning management systems and since I want to be able to export my questions to multiple formats (e.g. pdf, html), the CAS-assisted grading was an optional extra.

Comment: OK, I understand. Well, it really depends on the workflow you want to implement. If you want to use Moodle (or another learning management system), then the simplest way is to do the evaluation in Moodle. If you evaluate the exercises in another way and import the results back to R you can use any R package that you want. Hence, there is no reason to stick to what R/exams offers. I would recommend to accept my answer above - and in case you have a concrete question about a certain workflow and grading strategy you can ask a new question here on SO (not confined to R/exams).

Comment: Could you please either accept the answer or clarify what aspects are still unanswered? For a full grading workflow I would recommend to ask another more detailed question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Stack Exchange and so accepted it incorrectly last time. Hopefully this works now.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Now everything is flagged correctly.